# Is there a best practice for blog navigation matching the rest of the site?

Tags: navigation, blog

My company is currently in the process of redesigning the blog on its website for a web service product. Most of the site contains a global navigation menu with items such as: *How it works, Plans and Pricing, Why Us, Case Studies*, etc.

In terms of UX, would it be a bad move to use a different navigation menu from the rest of the site? We’re thinking a single CTA to encourage people to discover our offering might be more effective and easier for people to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a single UX source that encourages a changing (or disappearing) primary/utility navigation. As such, seems to me fairly obvious (for the reasons you have mentioned and more) that you would wish to keep the site identity, navigation, and header/footer on each and every page.

The only exception to this would be when a site is so big (say 8000 templates) that it calls for micro-sites. But your site seems rather small.

Also, I can only assume that people visiting your site, would not use the blog exclusively - they will be interested in the business offerings as well, which serves the business well. This further supports an integrated blog.

How a look at the [Sencha Website](http://www.sencha.com/) where both the blog and forum are integrated, an implementation that can be technically challenging for developers.

Answer (score 1):

For consistency purpose, it's good to have a global navigation across the entire site. Blog often has its own type of navigation (e.g. post categories) and they can be presented as a sub-navigation menu (usually displayed in the sidebar or below a global nav bar).

Some sites do have different navigation (or page layout) compare to the rest of the site and it works ok if most of the blog visitors are not actual site users. In that case links such as plans and pricing are not as important because you're not trying to convert them to paying customers/app users.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest terms, keep your global navigation and make any sub-navigation below the global or at the side.